# display a pdf in a modal window without downloaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I'm try to open a pdf in a modal window 
I face a problem with

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basic" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria- hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- hidden="true">
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe id="Iframe1" src="" runat="server" width="540" height="600"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn red btn-outline" data- dismiss="modal">
                        أغلق</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I give the iframe a src to display a pdf file,

```
frame1.Attributes.Add("src", "~/file.pdf");
```

the problem is the download manager force the file to download and not appear in modal, 
so I try that to add the code below, but it's open in all page not in modal

```
 string x ="~/file.pdf";

 Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
 Response.WriteFile(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(x));
 Response.End();
 frame1.Attributes.Add("src", x);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do 2 things, both related to the `content-disposition` in the header.
The key is returning the PDF with `content-disposition` `inline`.

So you could set that in the IIS:

- Go to the file
- Properties
- Headers
- Set Content-disposition, inline; filename="File1.pdf"

Or make your own FileDownloader.aspx. And there set the content disposition:

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"File1.pdf\"");
Response.WriteFile(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("file1.pdf"));
Response.End();
```

And in your iFrame you just target the downloader

```
 frame1.Attributes.Add("src", "FileDownloader.aspx");
```